# Restore SharePoint Web Application on a different Farm

Tags: 2010, backup, restore

If a perform a web application backup, can I restore it into a compeletely different farm with a different machine name but same sharepoint version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do that. SharePoint supports complete portability of its web application independent of the hardware/hostname/topology of the servers in the destination farm.

The minimum requirements are :-

1. Same SharePoint Edition and Version (Service Packs including)
2. SQL Server Edition must be compatible to restore your content database backups.